# iOS adhoc Enterprise Signed App Crashes Immediately on Some Devices

Tags: ios, crash, splash-screen, adhoc

The application is signed with an Enterprise account and works fine on most of devices, but on some different devices with different iOS versions crashes immediately on splash
here is the Console log:

```
default 17:25:19.364457 +0330   SpringBoard Bootstrapping "Bundl ID" with intent foreground-interactive
default 17:25:19.462242 +0330   symptomsd   664 "Bundl ID": ForegroundRunning (most elevated: ForegroundRunning)
default 17:25:19.743261 +0330   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER ["Bundl ID"]: isProcessLaunch: 1,    isForegroundActivation: 1,     isForegroundDeactivation: 0
default 17:25:19.882549 +0330   symptomsd   Entry, display name "Bundl ID" uuid 94CCE971-9F48-37E2-BB94-A7DD47298557 pid 664 isFront 1
default 17:25:19.885622 +0330   symptomsd   Continue with bundle name "Bundl ID", is front 1
default 17:25:19.886169 +0330   symptomsd   "Bundl ID": Foreground: true
default 17:25:19.933423 +0330   assertiond  Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x1014274d0; "App Name"; "Bundl ID"; pid: 664; agency: Application; visibility: foreground; task: none; hostpid: 50>
default 17:25:20.036993 +0330   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10a438400; "App Name" ("Bundl ID"); pid: 664> assertiond says the process actually exited with context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x281c2b0d0; reason: (none)>
default 17:25:20.037163 +0330   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10a438400; "App Name" ("Bundl ID"); pid: 664> exited.
default 17:25:20.045961 +0330   SpringBoard Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10a438400; "App Name" ("Bundl ID"); pid: -1>
default 17:25:20.137150 +0330   SpringBoard Front display did change: <SBApplication: 0x282104000; "Bundl ID">
default 17:25:20.197763 +0330   SpringBoard ["Bundl ID"] Will update scene - foregroundness changed to: Background
default 17:25:20.225123 +0330   assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:"Bundl ID"[0xb8ff][60]
default 17:25:20.225306 +0330   assertiond  ["App Name":664] Deleted launchd job with label: UIKitApplication:"Bundl ID"[0xb8ff][60]
default 17:25:20.288201 +0330   assertiond  Checking for deferred bootstrap request for "Bundl ID"
default 17:25:20.289644 +0330   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client "Bundl ID" with pid '664' is now Terminated. Background entitlement: NO
default 17:25:20.303932 +0330   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10a438400; "App Name" ("Bundl ID"); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x2810a8cc0; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)> {
    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x281f72180; pid: 664; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>;
}
default 17:25:20.304539 +0330   SpringBoard Application process state changed for "Bundl ID": (null)
default 17:25:20.373002 +0330   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER ["Bundl ID"]: isProcessLaunch: 0,    isForegroundActivation: 0,     isForegroundDeactivation: 1
default 17:25:20.373920 +0330   symptomsd   Failed to find process for "Bundl ID"
default 17:25:20.418162 +0330   symptomsd   664 "Bundl ID": Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
default 17:25:20.507758 +0330   symptomsd   Entry, display name "Bundl ID" uuid (null) pid 664 isFront 0
default 17:25:20.509119 +0330   symptomsd   Continue with bundle name "Bundl ID", is front 0
default 17:25:20.511078 +0330   symptomsd   "Bundl ID": Foreground: false
default 17:25:20.520161 +0330   symptomsd   Failed to find process for "Bundl ID"
```

Comment: we are having the exact same issue. Have you found any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Two things that could be happening that I think of when I see your logs:

- Enterprise apps need a network connection to verify the certificate. The device needs to be able to connect to https://ppq.apple.com. Are these devices online or behind a firewall?
- The way to trust a certificate on a device changed over the years. Does the device trust the enterprise certificate?

This link should give more context about these two issues: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204460

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both items you've mentioned are fine, still the issue exist.